# Not showing GPU, Installed tensroflow using anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, gpu

I installed tensorflow using below

```
conda create -n gpu_env tensorflow-gpu
conda activate gpu_env
```

and try to check gpu with this below code:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

output shows me only cpu.

```
2021-04-18 20:54:47.012684: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 9318913720310627740
]
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `tensorflow-gpu` installs `tensorflow v2.3.0` and currently, it does not install the conda cudnn or cudatoolkit packages. One thing you can do is install an earlier version of `tensorflow`, which does install `cudnn` and `cudatoolkit`, then upgrade with pip.

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.1
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.3.1
```

The `tensorflow` build automatically selected by Anaconda on Windows 10 during the installation of `tensorflow-gpu` seems to be faulty so check this workaround.

Comment: Hi Saurav, thank you so much. I have been looking for this for almost 3 weeks. no exaggeration. The workaround you suggested worked like a charm.

Comment: @CanerBurcBASKAYA Happy to help :)